# MS Graph: Get all users with direct assigned licenses in Office 365

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I found a series of scripts for getting this information on the following page under the topic "Check if user license is assigned directly or inherited from a group".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-ps-examples#check-if-user-license-is-assigned-directly-or-inherited-from-a-group

I will post it all combined in the code sample below, but I was hoping someone would be able to show me how I can trim the export to only show the users who have direct assigned licenses as opposed to all users, including those inherited from a group.

```
$skuId = "contoso:ENTERPRISEPACK"
$ExportPath = 'c:\temp\EnterprisePackLicensed.csv'

#Returns TRUE if the user has the license assigned directly
function UserHasLicenseAssignedDirectly
{
    Param([Microsoft.Online.Administration.User]$user, [string]$skuId)

    foreach($license in $user.Licenses)
    {
        #we look for the specific license SKU in all licenses assigned to the user
        if ($license.AccountSkuId -ieq $skuId)
        {
            #GroupsAssigningLicense contains a collection of IDs of objects assigning the license
            #This could be a group object or a user object (contrary to what the name suggests)
            #If the collection is empty, this means the license is assigned directly - this is the case for users who have never been licensed via groups in the past
            if ($license.GroupsAssigningLicense.Count -eq 0)
            {
                return $true
            }

            #If the collection contains the ID of the user object, this means the license is assigned directly
            #Note: the license may also be assigned through one or more groups in addition to being assigned directly
            foreach ($assignmentSource in $license.GroupsAssigningLicense)
            {
                if ($assignmentSource -ieq $user.ObjectId)
                {
                    return $true
                }
            }
            return $false
        }
    }
    return $false
}
#Returns TRUE if the user is inheriting the license from a group
function UserHasLicenseAssignedFromGroup
{
    Param([Microsoft.Online.Administration.User]$user, [string]$skuId)

    foreach($license in $user.Licenses)
    {
        #we look for the specific license SKU in all licenses assigned to the user
        if ($license.AccountSkuId -ieq $skuId)
        {
            #GroupsAssigningLicense contains a collection of IDs of objects assigning the license
            #This could be a group object or a user object (contrary to what the name suggests)
            foreach ($assignmentSource in $license.GroupsAssigningLicense)
            {
                #If the collection contains at least one ID not matching the user ID this means that the license is inherited from a group.
                #Note: the license may also be assigned directly in addition to being inherited
                if ($assignmentSource -ine $user.ObjectId)
                {
                    return $true
                }
            }
            return $false
        }
    }
    return $false
}

#find all users that have the SKU license assigned
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.Licenses.AccountSKUID -eq $skuId} | select `
    UserPRincipalName, `
    @{Name="SkuId";Expression={$skuId}}, `
    @{Name="AssignedDirectly";Expression={(UserHasLicenseAssignedDirectly $_ $skuId)}}, `
    @{Name="AssignedFromGroup";Expression={(UserHasLicenseAssignedFromGroup $_ $skuId)}} | export-csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

Comment: It seems you're only looking for one particular SkuId and want to know for each user if that is assigned directly of via group assinment, right?

Comment: Ideally, if it could run against all sku's in the same code, that would even be better. That said, if I need to have multiple scripts for multiple sku's, that will work also.

Comment: I think you need this one before run up remove the lines's wiht remove licenties. @khdoesntcode
 https://github.com/nicolonsky/Techblog/tree/master/CleanupAzureADLicensing